# UWP X:Bind and Design Time Data

Tags: xaml, design-time-data, uwp

is it possible to use x:bind and design time data in uwp apps?

e.g if I had a textbox that used x:bind to bind to a property on viewmodel in the code behind, should that property's value appear in the textbox in the designer?

is there a way of achieving this?

cheers

Johnny

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`x:Bind` doesn't support design-time data yet. Maybe it never will given it's designed for compile-time bindings to boost performance (I wish it would though).

For *simple* UI testing purposes, I would add a `FallbackValue` to the binding expression to force the designer to show me some dummy text. However, don't forget to remove it once you are done with the design.

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind MyMoney, FallbackValue='$10,000,000'}" />
```

**Update**

Now it's easier with the new design-time data support.

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind MyMoney}" d:Text="$10,000,000" />
```

Read more from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-designtime-data?view=vs-2019).

Comment: So inconvenient, I was so looking forward to this new binding expression. Can't give up design time data hence it'll have to be the old way! I tried something along the lines of: {x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentStyleDefinition.Primary.Color, FallbackValue={Binding CurrentStyleDefinition.Primary.Color}} but it seems the fallback value has to be a simple type :(